# Is there a way to enforce inequality constraints on widget size?

Tags: gwt

- I have a **CellTable** widget which displays some data.
- If there are many rows, I want the height of the widget to be **capped** at (say) 300 pixels (I can accomplish this by wrapping with a ScrollPanel).
- However, if there are only a **few** rows, I don't want the ScrollPanel to use all 300 pixels of height. I just want it to be tall enough to contain all the data.

It seems like I want to set a ScrollPanel height which means "as large as the data requires, but **no larger than** 300px."

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to manually re-set the height in accordance with this constraint every time the celltable's rowdata changes?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to put the `CellTable` in a `<div>` or `FlowPanel` and set a CSS `max-height: 300px` for that container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried this, and (1) everything looks great when the CellTable is short, but (2) When the CellTable has many rows, its display "spills out" beyond the dimensions of the FlowPanel. It appears that setting "max-height" on the FlowPanel somehow does not constrain the size of the embedded CellTable. Are there any additional style parameters I need to specify in the CellTable?

Comment: OK, it seems to work if I put the CellTable in a ScrollPanel, and set the "max-height" property on the ScrollPanel. No need for an enclosing div or FlowPanel. Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned that you also need `overflow: scroll` in addition to `max-height: 300px`; the point was: just use CSS.